# How to create a Generator keeps going after StopIteration?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

If I have multiple iterables as argument, and is there any way to keep the code going after one of the list raise StopIteration?

I cannot use any slicing, len(), or any itertools.

This is what I have tried so far, and I know it is totally wrong but I just cannot figure this out.

```
def together(*args):
    iterator = [iter(item) for item in args]
    my_list = []

    while True:
            for i in iterator:
                try:
                    lst.append(next(i))
                    print(next(i))
                except StopIteration:
                    return
            if '__next__' == None:
                yield tuple(None)
            else:
                yield tuple(my_list)
            my_list = []
```

Here is my current result, iter do store b,g,i but it only prints out first list:

```
[('a', 'f', 'h')]
```

Whats the best way to get a result like this?
Resutls are tuples in a list, and when argument iterables runs out then it get replaced with Nones.

```
[('a', 'f', 'h'), ('b', 'g', 'i'), ('c', None, 'j'), ('d', None, 'k'), ('e', None, None)]
```

I know the StopIteration error rises after the ('b','g','i'), but is there any way to ignore and keep going with different list?

And input looks like:

```
[v for v in together(disguise('abcde'), disguise('fg'), disguise('hijk'))]
```

disguise function looks like:

```
def disguise(items):
    for v in items:
        yield v
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated!

Comment: what's disguise? can you just provide the input as a normal list please

Comment: What is `myzip` here?

Comment: Input is yield value. I just edited the question for both, thanks!

Comment: You say "I cannot use any slicing, len(), or any itertools." Why not?

Comment: It is the part of requirement unfortunately.

Comment: Is it HW? Because looking at the python implementation of [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) would be very illustrative of certain subtle aspects of implementing this correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of `next` to let `next` return a default value instead of raising a `StopIteration` exception when a given iterator is exhausted:

```
def together(*seqs):
    seqs = list(map(iter, seqs))
    while True:
        group = tuple(next(seq, None) for seq in seqs)
        if all(i is None for i in group):
            return
        yield group
```

so that:

```
list(together('abcde', 'fg', 'hijk'))
```

returns:

```
[('a', 'f', 'h'), ('b', 'g', 'i'), ('c', None, 'j'), ('d', None, 'k'), ('e', None, None)]
```

Comment: You should probably explicitly call `iter` on each of the args passed in, then it would work on any iterable not just iterators. Also, `any(group)` is potentially a bug, if the iterators produce falsy values

Comment: In your solution the input sequences/iterators should not contain `None` otherwise `together` could prematurely terminate. However, since this is a toy problem I don't think this matters that much.